# Reloading custom UITableViewCell after reordering cells

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitableview

I have  `UITableView` which uses custom `UITableViewCell`s. The cells can have one of three types of background images (set in each cell's `.backgroundView.image` property): top, middle, or bottom. The top and bottom images are for the first and last cells, and have rounded corners (much like a grouped `UITableView`'s cells). All other "middle" cells within the `UITableView` have a rectangular middle background image.

My problem is that when reordering the cells in the `UITableView`'s **Edit** mode the cells do not refresh with a different background image depending on their new location. For example, if I move the first cell into the middle of the table it still retains its original "top" background image (with rounded corners) and the new cell which appears at the top of the table view still has its original "middle" background image, which all looks a bit odd.

I can get around this by doing a `reloadData` on the table view, but this has the problem of not giving a nice graceful animation of the changes. I noticed that when reordering a standard grouped `UITableView` as soon as a cell is moved / dragged the background image on the relevant cells change (even before the moved cell has been dropped into its new location) which looks very nice. I would like to achieve the same thing.

To this end, I have implemented `tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath` which is called every time a row is dragged around in the table view. Within this I have tried various methods of setting the `backgroundView.image` including just directly setting the image and then also explicitly telling it to redraw the cell and/or image using `setNeedsLayout` and `setNeedsDisplay` but nothing seems to make the cell redraw. I have `NSLog`'ged the results of these changes and they appear to be committing to the cell, as the correct values appear in the `NSLog`, but the cell just does not seem to be updating on screen.

If anyone could point out what I am doing wrong, or suggest a better way of achieving a working outcome, I would be very much appreciative. Thanks!

EDIT: the following code was pulled from the bounty and formatted so it can be more easily digested:

```
UIImage *rowBackground;
UIImage *selectionBackground;
NSInteger sectionRows = [_tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];
NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
if (row == 0 && row == sectionRows - 1)
{
    rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"field_title_bkg.png"];
    selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"field_title_bkg.png"];
}
else if (row == 0)
{
    rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table_row_top_bkg.png"];
    selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table_row_top_bkg.png"];
}
else if (row == sectionRows - 1)
{
    rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table_bottom_row_bkg.png"];
    selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table_bottom_row_bkg.png"];
}
else
{
    rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table_row_bkg.png"];
    selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table_row_bkg.png"];
}
UIImageView *rowBackGroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:rowBackground];
UIImageView *rowBackGroundSelectionImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:selectionBackground];
if (row != sectionRows - 1)
{
    UIImageView *sep = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_separator.png"]];
    [sep setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 56, 280, 1)];
    [rowBackGroundImageView addSubview:sep];
}
[cell setBackgroundView:rowBackGroundImageView];
[rowBackGroundImageView release];
```

Comment: You can try masking the tableview with another view on top of it. Then you won't need backgorund images for cells at all.

Comment: Could you explain this idea a bit more? I don't quite follow how that would work.

Comment: A related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338161/update-old-new-top-bottom-cells-backgroundview-when-inserting-deleting-top-bott

Comment: Is your `- (void)tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` on your delegate being called? I've found the most reliable place to customize backgrounds is in that method.

Comment: I think this has something to do with the cell still being edited. You can try the following code but be aware that it's not thread-safe to draw in background and you shouldn't use it at all - just for testing: `[tableView performSelectorInBackground:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil]; // or setNeedsDisplay:`

Answer (score 5):

Write below code in your project and it should work as per expectations.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath
      toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
{
    NSInteger sectionRows = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[sourceIndexPath section]];

    UITableViewCell *sourceCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath];
    UITableViewCell *destCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:proposedDestinationIndexPath];

    if(sourceIndexPath.row == 0 && proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == 1)
    {
        ((UIImageView *)destCell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table_row_top_bkg.png"];

        if(proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == sectionRows - 1)
            ((UIImageView *)sourceCell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table_bottom_row_bkg.png"];
        else
            ((UIImageView *)sourceCell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table_row_bkg.png"];
    }

    else if(sourceIndexPath.row == sectionRows - 1 && proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == sectionRows - 2)
    {
        ((UIImageView *)destCell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table_bottom_row_bkg.png"];

        if(proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == 0)
            ((UIImageView *)sourceCell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table_row_top_bkg.png"];
        else
            ((UIImageView *)sourceCell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table_row_bkg.png"];
    }

    else if(proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == 0)
    {
        ((UIImageView *)sourceCell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table_row_top_bkg.png"];

        destCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:proposedDestinationIndexPath.section]];
        if(sectionRows == 2)
            ((UIImageView *)destCell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table_bottom_row_bkg.png"];
        else
            ((UIImageView *)destCell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table_row_bkg.png"];
    }

    else if(proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == sectionRows - 1)
    {
        ((UIImageView *)sourceCell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table_bottom_row_bkg.png"];

        destCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sectionRows - 1 inSection:proposedDestinationIndexPath.section]];
        if(sectionRows == 2)
            ((UIImageView *)destCell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table_row_top_bkg.png"];
        else
            ((UIImageView *)destCell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table_row_bkg.png"];
    }

    return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! My accessory view seems to have disappeared but I was thinking of doing a custom one anyways.

Comment: So, if you drag a row to a different row, then decide you don't want it there before letting go of the drag, the image changes to the wrong cell image :/

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to reload a few cells rather the entire table you can use:

```
reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
```

available as an instance method of UITableView.

Comment: Hi Robert. Tried that, but it won't work in the `tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath` method (i.e. while the row is being dragged / moved around) and crashes with the message that the number of rows and sections after the animation must match the number before the animation. Not surprising given that the rows are still being moved around when we try and call this method.

Comment: Have you tried to perform the reloading in the UITableViewDataSource method `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` instead? I think that one is called after the move is completed.

Comment: Hi Robert. Sorry about the late reply. I tried this as well, but it causes some strange behavior. If I only reload `toIndexPath` it will make the row at `fromIndexPath` completely disappear. If I reload both index paths it will really go hay-wire and start putting multiple copies of cells on top of each other!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried myself but why not test your indexPath.row value on the cellForRowAtIndexPath method and provide the different backgroundView.image values for first and last row?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

I hope this helps.
Cheers,
Rog

Comment: Hi Rog. That is what I am currently doing, but `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not called when the row is moved as the row is already on screen. I have tried manually calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in the `tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath` method but nothing happens (i.e. the cell does not reload / redraw on screen).

Answer (score 0):

**`(this solution only works for the reordering of rows within the same section. It'll fail when dragging and dropping rows to a different section)`**

I had the same problem when updating a cell's detail label text after being reordered.

I solved it with the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath  toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath 
{
UITableViewCell* cell = [self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:fromIndexPath]; 
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"NEW STRING";
}
```

Note that you have to update the cell at **`fromIndexPath`**, because it seems that the internal state of the tableview doesn't update until this method returns. If you get the cell at `toIndexPath`, after reordering finishes, you will see the neighbor cell gets updated. (either top or bottom one).

Answer (score 0):

the apis for partially reloading rows in the ios sdk doesn't function well (that's why ppl follow this post here)

I end up using timer to reload the whole data after reordering animation finishes.
It works for me.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath 
{
    //things to be done when reordering rows
    ....


    //issue a timer to reload data
    NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1
                                             target: self
                                           selector:@selector(updateRow)
                                           userInfo: nil repeats:NO];


}


-(void) updateRow
{

    [self.table reloadData];

}
```

Comment: not sure you need to use a timer--you can just use `-performSelectorOnMainThread:`