# Update old/new top/bottom cells' backgroundView when inserting/deleting top/bottom cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

This is the template code given in the doc of `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
    atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
    atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
    newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                  atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

With this code, default grouped styled table view updates its cells nicely with background view change animations: when deleting the first cell, the second cell becomes the first with its top corners changing from square to round, and things like that.

However, for cells with custom `backgroundView`，table view does not do the same background view transitions for us. So we'll see things like this:

Before deleting the first row [image: Before deleting]

After deleting the first row [image: After deleting]

How can I restore the nice animation with proper background view updates?

Comment: Did you try reloading the row that is now at the top (using [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:<> withRowAnimation:<>]) after deleting the row?

Comment: I can reload the row in this case. But there are many different cases, I want a general way of handling all of them. Now I'm using very complex code in `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods and I want to know whether there is a magic trigger that can be used to apply the nice animation of default grouped table views to customized  grouped table views, or whether anyone else has easier and cleverer implementations.

Comment: if you are using image for background view then you have to make it round looking your self.

Comment: Does it work properly if you just call `[self.tableView reloadData]` in `controllerDidChangeContent:`? If so, it could be a viable solution, if reloading the data is cheap.

Comment: @Danra But I still want the nice animation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in, simple way to manage the cell animations with a custom cell background on a grouped tableview.

You either maintain a list of cells whose background needs redrawing then use `[cell.backgroundView setNeedsDisplay]`

Or you could consider masking the tableview. So you have one cell background but they are clipped see [Round corners on UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106861/round-corners-on-uitableview)

Comment: Also may be worth mentioning that UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic is available in iOS5 which may look better than the fade animation you are using.